# Can Salient Theme Nectar Slider support transparent background image?

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, themes, transparent

I'm editing a website which was designed in Wordpress with the Salient theme including Nectar Sliders.

The Nectar Slider automatically fills image transparent backgrounds with black.  There don't seem to be any options for this in Wordpress.

Is there a css file that can be modified?

Comment: Most likely there is, but to find it you'll need to dig a bit (unless someone happens to know the same theme/slider). If you right click in your browser on the element and look for 'inspect element' or something similar, and look around in there around the element it opens up on, you might be able to find the CSS rule you need to override.

Comment: No browser renders transparent as black by default - therefor no CSS would help. So either your image is corrupted *(is it shown correctly transparent, when the original image is opened in the browser?)* or your WordPress re-renders the image and the library used for that is not working correctly or can't handle your file. *(For instance I had some issues with resizing transparent GIFs in WordPress. Try using Original Size.)*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stylesheets for installed themes are located in Appearance > Editor, and are
hidden until you select the theme on the right.

It looks like Salient's Nectar Slider in particular cannot have a transparent background.  Overriding background-color to transparent makes the actual image transparent.